# Phone Input Mask inputs starts at end of line

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the need of 2 input boxes with a Phone Mask. Currently using maked input from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. Input 1 is in the body of my page and works as expected.

```
<input type="text" id= "s_id" name="s_id" class="form-control" 
placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx">
```

and above header:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#s_id").mask("(999) 999-9999");


$("#s_id").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 3 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
        var lastfour = move + last;

        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

        $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
    }
});
}); 

</script>
```

My problem is Input 2 which is in a Bootstrap popover container.

```
<input type="text" id= "phone" name="phone" class="form-control" 
placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx">
```

My logical step would be to create a second script with a different input ID.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");


$("#phone").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 3 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
        var lastfour = move + last;

        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

        $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
    }
});
});
```

Problem is that 2nd input mask does not work in my Bootstrap popover.

I even tried a second input mask script from http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask which worked successfully except that for input 2, the mask focus is at the end of the input box instead of at the first character of the input box. Any help would be appreciated with either input mask script.

Answer (score 0):

On `$(window).load` (when the page loads), `$("#phone")` probably doesn't exist yet, because it is inside a popover, which requires an user interaction to become available. So you can't do:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
})
```

But you can use the popover events from bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events

And try something like this:

```
$('#myPopoverThatContainsPhone').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $("#phone", this).mask("(999) 999-9999");
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result of the mask not appearing in the popover using method 1 with your solution.

Comment: Another possibility would be if anyone can help me select all in input box when popover is clicked using the Jasny.net input mask.